# I seem to have broken Java after installing Nokia Ovi Suite

Tags: installation, java, java-applet, nokia-ovi-suite

I just installed Nokia Ovi Suite for syncing photos from my phone and such, but the program won't open, and nor will any of my other Java applications.

I tried installing latest version of Java (didn't uninstall, just installed new one) but that didn't help.

My PC is running Windows 7 64 bit.

What's gone wrong and how do i fix it?

Comment: "didn't uninstall, just installed a new one".  Installing a new one, doesn't always fix the errors of the previous one.  Uninstall, and reinstall and see what that does first.

Comment: Uninstall all Java versions and reinstall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out myself the second time I broke it: don't panic! Don't uninstall or update Java. Just change the default program for opening Java applications back to java itself.

Steps to take:

- right click on a Java app or a shortcut to a java app;
- go to "properties";
- go to the "general" tab of the properties window;
- where it says "opens with" click change.

For me there was an option of "Java (TM) platform SE binaries". I switched to that, and now all my Java apps seem to open with Java.